# Get domain without subdomains in Java?

Tags: java, subdomain

The below code prints `www.sub.google.com`.

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class GetDomainNameFromURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        String s = "http://www.sub.google.com/main?&t=20&f=52";
        URL u = new URL(s);
        String hostName = u.getHost();
        System.out.println(hostName);
    }
}
```

How to print `google.com`? Need to use plain `Java`, no `Guava` libraries.

Comment: what do **you** consider a domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky because the `URL` class can only get you so far. It gives you the *hostname* and then it's up to you to extract the *domain name* minus the *subdomain*.

To identify the *domain name* here you need to know what TLDs (*top level domains* like .com, .co etc.) or ccTLDs (*country code TLDs* like .co.uk, .uk etc.) you're expecting beforehand because that would determine from where (which `.` dot) your domain name starts.

For example, the following regex:

```
(?<=.)[^.]+\.(com|co(\.uk)?|uk)$
```

would identify the following domain names for you:

> www.**google.com**
>   mail.**google.co**
>   www.**google.co.uk**
>   www.sub.**google.uk**

A more generic solution would require to make assumptions beforehand like a TLD or ccTLD will have no more than two or three characters to differentiate them from the main domain but with newer TLDs like .guru, .photos, .expert, .legal etc. it's not possible to make it work for all the domains anymore.